# what does that operator means between 2 numbers?

Tags: operator-theory

(I couldn't write the operator in the title)
It's ∨ as in a ∨ b = 839 e.g.
I know this operator from boolean logic but I was surprised to find it in arithmetic.
It was a question to find a and b to find a and b if a + b = 770 and a ∨ b = 735 e.g.
Any idea?

Comment: One standard though not terribly common meaning is the maximum of the two numbers, $a\land b$ being the minimum. That can’t be the intent here, however, since $2\cdot62=124<720$, so there are no numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b=720$ and the maximum of $a$ and $b$ is $62$.

Comment: Sometimes $a\vee b$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, whereas $a\wedge b$ is the greatest common divisor.

Comment: @Brian I will give the right numbers, edit the question

Comment: @YoussefDir: With those numbers it could be the maximum: take $a=735$ and $b=770-735=35$, or $b=735$ and $a=770-735=35$.

Comment: I have a feeling it's the least common multiple since it's a main topic in the exam I was reading

Comment: @YoussefDir: In that case it probably is the least common multiple. I’ve not tried to solve it on that assumption, but if that is the intended reading, it will be useful to know that $735=3\cdot5\cdot7^2$.

Comment: It can be the least common multiple as well with $a=35=5\cdot 7$ and $b=735$. It's the only solution up to symmetry.